# Virtualbox VM not booting from separate hard drive

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a bit of a problem with Oracle's Virtualbox. Before I upgraded my pc with an SSD I ran VB with 64-bit Ubuntu on my Win7 system, all worked good etc. Now I'm running my pc off the SSD which I installed, complete with a fresh Win7. I still want to be able to access my old Ubuntu VM though, so I found the folder containing the .vbox file and the much larger .vdi file (Users\USERNAME\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu64), downloaded the latest VM VirtualBox software and ran it on my new SSD Win7 install, using "Machine"->"Add" in the VM manager to reference my old .vdi/.vbox file.

First problem was that it complained about my CPU not having hardware virtualization enabled, so I checked the BIOS; it was enabled (this being a i7-2600k), and after checking that problem went away. Now, however, when I run it, I get a screen as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB4ff.jpg

I've tried the top two options with nothing but a black screen following. I really want to be able to get back into this VM, since I had some good code there...

Comment: It is a perfectly healthy answer: it is the GRUB screen, just hit Enter and the VM will boot.

Comment: You mean the purple screen is the GRUB screen? I do hit enter, but as I said in my post, the only thing that follows is a black screen with a _ in the top left corner, which responds to no input whatsoever.

Comment: Did you change the default location? Open the preference section in the VirtualBox main manager and change the default location to the new place

Comment: Changed it to G:\Users\USERNAME\VirtualBox VMs\, but no change in my results. GRUB screen, then nothing but black screen.

Comment: Is the new version of VirtualBox very different from the one ith which the VM was created?

Comment: The old one was 4.1.X, new one is 4.3.6... doesn't seem like there should be a huge difference?